# Show two divs alternatively on mouse over and out

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have below given two div elements. I want to show one div at a time. One div on mouseout and one div on mouseover without jquery. Thanks in advance

```
<div style= 'position: absolute;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;background:#ccc;color:#ffffff;height:15px; width:100px;text-align: center;color:#fff'><a href="http://facebook.com/site=1" target="_blank"> Facebook Ads</a> </div><div style= 'position: absolute;right: 0px;bottom: 0px;background:#ccc;color:#ffffff;height:15px; width:15px;text-align: center;'> Ads </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple CSS way to do what you want.

toggle the visibility of the divs on hover. This way involves wrapping the two divs inside a parent.

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.first {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}

.second {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover > .first {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover > .second {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.first {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.second {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent:hover>.first {
  display: block;
}

.parent:hover>.second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class='first'><a href="http://facebook.com/site=1" target="_blank"> Facebook Ads</a> </div>
  <div class='second'> Ads </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using javascript

First assign ID to your div.. Say div1 and div 2... Now on mouseout event call a JavaScript function to show div2 and hide div1

```
function onMouseOut{
         document.getElemwntById("div1"). style.display = "none";

    document.getElemwntById("div2"). style.display = "block";

    }
```

Similarly on mouseover call a JavaScript function as below to show div1 and hide div2

```
function onMouseOver{
         document.getElemwntById("div2"). style.display = "none";

    document.getElemwntById("div1"). style.display = "block";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In code below you can see a similar solution with pure CSS with less code and better optimized.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}

.fb-ads,
.ads {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
/*   height: 20px; */ /* Active it if you want to add height*/
  color: #fff; 
  text-align: center;
  background: #aaa;
}

.container:hover .ads {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="fb-ads" href="http://facebook.com/site=1" target="_blank">Facebook Ads</a> 
  <div class="ads">Ads</div>
</div>
```

or look here https://codepen.io/artysimple/pen/LzdGbe?editors=1100